# one column in GridView won't export to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, visual-studio, gridview

I have a GridView displaying fields from a database and a function to export this GridView to an Excel spreadsheet but the only column not displaying is litChecklistNo.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
                            <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VehicleReg" HeaderText="Registration" SortExpression="VehicleReg"></asp:BoundField> 
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Checklist Number" SortExpression="CheckListNo">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Literal ID="litChecklistNo" runat="server"> </asp:Literal>
                                        </ItemTemplate> 
                                    </asp:TemplateField>  
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" SortExpression="ChecklistDate"  dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField> 
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MaintenanceNo" HeaderText="Maintenance No" SortExpression="MaintenanceNo"></asp:BoundField>    
                                </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

The code to export the GridView:

```
protected void ToExcel(GridView grid, string Name, string FileName)
    {
        if (!FileName.Contains(".xls"))
        {
            FileName = FileName + ".xls";
        }
        string style = "<style><!--table@page{mso-header-data:\"&C" + Name + " Date/: &D/ Page &P\"; mso-page-orientation:landscape; mso-page-scale:89;}     br     {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}  --></style>";

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + "");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
        Response.Write("<head>");
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\">");
        Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
        Response.Write("<xml>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("<x:Name>" + Name + " Table</x:Name>");
        Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("<x:Panes>");
        Response.Write("</x:Panes>");
        Response.Write("<x:Print>");
        Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
        Response.Write("<x:Scale>89</x:Scale>");
        Response.Write("</x:Print>");
        Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("</xml>");
        Response.Write("<![endif]-->");
        Response.Write("</head>");
        Response.Write("<body>");

        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

        ClearControls(grid);

        grid.RenderBeginTag(oHtmlTextWriter);
        grid.HeaderRow.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            row.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        }
        grid.FooterRow.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        grid.RenderEndTag(oHtmlTextWriter);

        Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());


        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
        Response.End();

    }
```

litChecklistNo is a link in the GridView that opens another page when clicked so that is why I'm not using BoundField like in the rest of the GridView but why isn't it being exported to the Spreed sheet? Is it something to do with Literal?

Comment: Instead of manually building up all that markup, why don't you use a library that supports proper generation of `.xlsx` files such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), or [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)? I describe how to use EPPlus on [my blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net).

Comment: @mason for now I will continue using this code. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my post. I was having trouble exporting from my gridview to Excel as well. I was however using a masterpage to export from a page using this masterpage.

Follow to this link. Please note that this is VB.net, so you can just convert this code to C#.

[Exporting Gridview to Excel Vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400136/exporting-gridview-to-excel-vb-net/31557307#31557307)

Hope this helps.